# htaccess rewrite - Associating subfolders of web root as index of domain

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying to find specific information on the problem, but it all seems rather confusing or irrelevant.

I have an Apache install with several subfolders with different websites. I need requests for foo.com to redirect to .../htdocs/foo.

I'm trying to avoid the web address appearing in the browser as foo.com/foo, instead appearing as foo.com.

Is this possible?

Comment: If I can give you a suggestion, unless you want to learn, you can get this done in 1 minute with a cPanel shared hosting by clicking a button called "add Addon domain". It will cost you not more than 50 bucks per year. It's worth the time you would waste setting up your own Apache config and it will for sure run in a more scure environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in the httpd.conf file not with .htaccess, here are some examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html